# Where "character viewer" data is stored?

Tags: macos, parsing, unicode

I need to parse all data from Character Viewer on Mac, how can I do it? Or where is it stored?

I need this format:

☀︎
BLACK SUN WITH RAYS
Unicode: U+2600 U+FE0E, UTF-8: E2 98 80 EF B8 8E

☼
WHITE SUN WITH RAYS
Unicode: U+263C, UTF-8: E2 98 BC

and so on.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Personally, I use [this command-line utility](https://github.com/garabik/unicode/blob/master/README). It's written in Python so it should work fine on your Mac. Note that it allows you to specify a precise output format, which greatly simplifies parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OS X El Capitan (Version 10.11.6), the "Character Viewer" data can be found inside the package of the "Character Palette" system application located at `/System/Library/Input Methods/CharacterPalette.app`, in the SQLite database file: `/System/Library/Input Methods/CharacterPalette.app/Contents/Resources/CharacterDB.sqlite3`.

You can use an appropriate application (such as [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/)) to open the database file and export its main table to a file in CSV format, then extract the data by yourself.

In JavaScript (Node.js), provided you already know how to read the file lines, that would be something like:

```js
let lines =
[
    "☼ WHITE SUN WITH RAYS|||||||||||||||",
    "☀︎ BLACK SUN WITH RAYS|||||||||||||||",
    "☀️ BLACK SUN WITH RAYS|||||||||||||||",
    "☀ BLACK SUN WITH RAYS|||||||||||||||"
];
for (let line of lines)
{
    let fields = line.split ('\t');
    let characterSequence = fields[0];
    let name = fields[1].split ('|')[0];
    let codePoints = Array.from (characterSequence).map (char => "U+" + char.codePointAt (0).toString (16).toUpperCase ().padStart (4, "0")).join (" ");
    console.log (characterSequence, name, "Unicode:", codePoints);
}
```

Notes:

- The name of the main table (unihan_dict) is somehow misleading, but it contains data for all non-Unihan characters as well, with minimal information though.
- The Unicode character codes are not stored in the database file, since this would be redundant, but they can be easily computed.

Comment: Hello! Thanks a lot! I found English version of texts. However if I change my system language to another (like Russian) I see Russian names of Emojis in "Character Viewer", but couldn't find it in CharacterDB.sqlite3. Do you know where those are stored?